# Did the Spartans really taunt Philip II of Macedon with a single word?

Tags: ancient-greece, sparta

I came across this excerpt that was put up as a "joke" in an issue of the *Reader's Digest*:

> After invading Greece, Philip II of Macedon sent a threatening message to the Spartans: "You are advised to submit without delay, for if I bring my army on your land, I will destroy your farms, slay your people and raze your city."
>
> The Spartans replied with one word: "If"

Given the modern-day image of the Spartans being superb, tough warriors, and the hilarity of this "joke" aside...

1) **Did Philip II actually send this message to the Spartans? When was this?**

2) **Did the Spartans actually taunt him with the word "if"?**

3) **If not the above, did something even remotely similar occur?**

Comment: @user2448131 Well, you could've put that up as an answer ._.

Comment: Was looking up the actual historical reference.

Comment: Why the down votes? I've heard this story many times as well but never bothered to check it's veracity. Seems a reasonable question to me.

Comment: @TheHon *Bows down in gratitude*

Comment: I imagine the downvotes were due to the original wording of the question.  It seemed less historical and more trivial. Good Edit.

Comment: Re "...the modern image of the Spartans...", you've got to be kidding.  Spartans had that image long before movies were even invented.  Indeed, I didn't even know such a movie existed until just now.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Plutarch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plutarch), in [*De garrulitate*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A2008.01.0288%3Asection%3D17) , writes this concerning the brief, concise language used by the [Laconians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laconia):

> The Lacedaemonians to Philip; Dionysius in Corinth. And when Philip
>   wrote thus to the Spartans: If once I enter into your territories, I
>   will destroy ye all, never to rise again; they answered him with the
>   single word, If. To King Demetrius exclaiming in a great rage, What!
>   have the Spartans sent me but one ambassador? the ambassador nothing
>   terrified replied, Yes; one to one. Certainly they that spoke short
>   and concisely were much admired by the [p. 244] ancients.

see also [Laconic Phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laconic_phrase), where the following is noted (emphasis mine):

> Subsequently, **neither Philip nor his son Alexander the Great attempted
>   to capture the city**. Philip is also recorded as approaching Sparta on
>   another (?) occasion and asking whether he should come as friend or
>   foe; the reply was "Neither".[5]

So I guess one word was sufficient.

Comment: [Anthony ("***Nuts!***") McAuliffe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthony_McAuliffe) at Bastogne in 1944 also appreciated a Laconic sense of humour.

Comment: Agreed. (Also discussed [here](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/40063/what-did-general-mcauliffe-actually-say-at-bastogne))